# Android App Development - Implement Signal Tracker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to create a simple module based on this mobile apps developed by other developers.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.raymaps.rf.planner1

I'm new to android development. Therefore, I need hints to start on it.

My questions are:

1)How do integrate a google maps in my own android app? Is this the correct API?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

2)How can I plot a circle on the maps within my app?The circle I'm talking about refers to transmission coverage where after correct formulation, it will generate a circle on the maps based on the value?

I did go through some tutorial videos related to android development. However, all were teaching basics instead of moving into specific lesson such as my case. If any of you have a useful links related to my situation, I hope you guys could share with me :-)

Answer (score 0):

> How do integrate a google maps in my own android app? Is this the correct API? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Yes.

> How can I plot a circle on the maps within my app?

Use [a `Circle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html):

```
Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
  .center(new LatLng(40.708876, -74.006689))
  .radius(500)
  .strokeColor(Color.RED));
```

That puts a 500m red circle around [the Stack Exchange Galactic Headquarters](https://stackexchange.com/about/contact).